# Should every db query be wrapped in a try/catch block

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, node-postgres

If my controller makes multiple db queries in the same async function should each db query be wrapped in it's own individual try/catch block or is it fine to have all db queries in the same try/catch? What is the reasoning for either option?

### All db queries in their own try/catch example:

```
const confirmEmailVerification = async (req, res) => {

  const { token } = req.body;

  let user;
  try {
    const result = await db.query(
      'SELECT user_account_id FROM user_account WHERE email_verification_token = $1',
      [token]
    );

    if (result.rows.length === 0) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json('Please verify your account by clicking the link in your email');
    }

    user = result.rows[0].user_account_id;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    return res.status(500).json('Server Error');
  }

  try {
    const active = await db.query(
      'UPDATE user_account SET email_verified = TRUE WHERE user_account_id = $1',
      [user]
    );

    return res.status(200).json({
      message: 'Email has been verified, Please login',
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    return res.status(500).json('Server Error');
  }
};
```

### All db queries in the same try/catch example:

```
const confirmEmailVerification = async (req, res) => {

  const { token } = req.body;

  let user;
  try {
    const result = await db.query(
      'SELECT user_account_id FROM user_account WHERE email_verification_token = $1',
      [token]
    );

    if (result.rows.length === 0) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json('Please verify your account by clicking the link in your email');
    }

    user = result.rows[0].user_account_id;

    const active = await db.query(
      'UPDATE user_account SET email_verified = TRUE WHERE user_account_id = $1',
      [user]
    );

    return res.status(200).json({
      message: 'Email has been verified, Please login',
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    return res.status(500).json('Server Error');
  }
};
```

Comment: To some extent person preference - I would go for the second

Comment: I would drop the SELECT-statement and just do the UPDATE, including the email verification in the WHERE condition. Twice as fast and same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on that, if you want the sequence of functions to continue after previous function throws error.
In your case it is useless, because in either errors you finish with `res.status(500).json('Server Error')`.
But sometimes you want to continue, even if some of the functions in the chain throws error, eg.:

```
let errors = []
try {
  f1()
} catch (e) {
  errors.push(e)
}

try {
    f2()
} catch (e) {
    errors.push(e)
}

try {
    f3()
} catch (e) {
    errors.push(e)
}
```

If you put this is in one try/catch block, you would stop on the error of `f1()` and `f2()` and `f3()` would not be ran at all.

```
try {
    f1()
    f2()
    f3()
} catch (e) {
    something... 
}
```